# ¿Como desactivar el horario de verano en Dayjs con el timezone en 'America/Mexico_City'?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript

¡Hola a todos!

Estoy buscando ayuda para resolver un problema relacionado con Day.js y el horario de verano. Actualmente estoy utilizando Day.js en mi proyecto y necesito desactivar el horario de verano para evitar complicaciones.

He intentado varias soluciones, pero aún no he encontrado la configuración correcta para lograrlo. Mi objetivo es asegurarme de que las fechas y horas en Day.js se mantengan consistentes y no se vean afectadas por los cambios de horario de verano.

He investigado un poco y he encontrado que puedo utilizar la biblioteca adicional moment-timezone junto con Day.js para lograrlo. Sin embargo, no estoy seguro de utilizar moment-timezone porque dayjs() sigue dando la hora de más y con moment() ya no, el objetivo es no utilizar moment().

Si alguien tiene experiencia con Day.js y ha enfrentado un problema similar, les agradecería mucho si pudieran proporcionarme orientación o ejemplos de configuración para desactivar el horario de verano en Day.js.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda o sugerencia que puedan brindarme. ¡Gracias de antemano por su colaboración!

Saludos cordiales

Mi configuración con dayjs

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';
import timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone';
import isSameOrBefore from 'dayjs/plugin/isSameOrBefore';
import customFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat';
import 'dayjs/locale/es';
dayjs.extend(isSameOrBefore);
dayjs.extend(customFormat);
dayjs.extend(timezone);
dayjs.extend(utc);
dayjs.locale('es', {}, true);
dayjs.tz.setDefault('America/Mexico_City');
export default dayjs;
```

Cuando utilizo la funcion dayjs() para crear una nueva fecha sale así...

```
console.log(new Date()); // 2023-05-23T17:16:28.913Z
console.log(dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')); //  2023-05-23 12:16:28
```

Pero el resultado esperado y correcto sería el siguiente:

```
console.log(dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')); // 2023-05-23 11:16:28
```

Es decir, una hora menos, ya que en el país se ha desactivado el horario de verano.

Comment: El problema no es DayJS ni Moment, el problema (si acaso es un problema) es el objeto Date de Javascript, el cual te devolverá siempre el valor de fecha ajustado a la zona horaria del host: cliente donde se ejecute el código, ya sea el navegador o NodeJS.

Comment: Es que la situación es, que con moment-timezone con la configuración de desactivar el horario de verano si funciona, pero con dayjs no funciona :c
Y el objetivo es utilizar dayjs